# Distribution probability, show that $c=(m-1)!$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If we define the distribution probability function:$$ f(p_{1},..., p_{m}) = \left \{ \begin{matrix} c & 0\leq p_{i}\leq 1,  i=\{1,..., m\}, \sum_{i=1}^{m}{p_{i}}=1
\\ 0 & \mbox{otherwise }\end{matrix}\right. $$

Which is a special case of Dirichlet distribution, where $p_{i}$ is a probability. I wanna determine the value of $c$, for this, I know that the integral of the distribution must be equal to 1, so follow the Ian's comment $p_{1}$ can be anything between $0$ and $1$; $p_{2}$ needs to be between $0$ and $1−p_{1}$; $p_{3}$ needs to be between $0$ and $1−p_{1}−p_{2}$ etc, we have for $m=3$ 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-p_{1}}{cdp_{2}dp_{1}}=\dfrac{c}{2!}=1$$
Then, $c=2!=(3-1)!$. For $m=4$, we have
$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-p_{1}}\int_{0}^{1-p_{1}-p_{2}}{cdp_{3}dp_{2}dp_{1}}=\dfrac{c}{3!}=1$$
Then, $c=3!=(4-1)!$, and so on. So, now the question is for what reason when I considerer minus one variable this works??.. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed the integral is not over the $m$-dimensional cube $p_{i}\in [0,1]$ for every $i$ but over the $(m-1)$-dimensional intersection of this cube with the hyperplane $p_1+\cdots+p_m=1$--hence the result is not $c\cdot1=c$.

Comment: mm okay, I don't understand all your comment, but anyway I don't see how determine c. Thanks!

Comment: "I don't see how determine c" ?? As explained in my first comment, by computing the integral of $1$ over the simplex and deducing that $c=1/$this integral.

Comment: Okay, but what is a simplex???  I never heard this

Comment: $$\{(p_i)_{1\leqslant i\leqslant m}\in\mathbb R^m\mid p_1+\cdots+p_m=1,\,\forall i,\,p_i\geqslant0\}$$

Comment: Hint: $p_1$ can be anything between $0$ and $1$; $p_2$ needs to be between $0$ and $1-p_1$; $p_3$ needs to be between $0$ and $1-p_1-p_2$; etc.

Comment: @Ian, Okey, then $\int_{0}^{1-(p_{1}+...+p_{m-1})}\cdots\int_{0}^{1-p_{1}}\int_{0}^{1}{dp_{1}... dp_{m}}=(1-p_{1})(1-(p_{1}+p_{2}))\cdots   (1-(p_{1}+...+p_{m-1}))$

Comment: Your limits need to go the other way, which makes the calculation significantly more complicated.

Comment: @Ian what do you mean?

Comment: You say, $\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1-p_{1}}...\int_{0}^{1-p_{1}-...-p_{m-1}}{dp_{1}....dp_{m}}$??

Comment: @Ian Any way, how appear the term (m-1)!??

Comment: Say $m=3$; then you want $\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} \int_0^{1-x-y} dz dy dx$. But that's $\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} 1-x-y dy dx = \int_0^1 (1-x)^2-(1-x)^2/2 dx = \int_0^1 u^2/2 du = 1/6$. Try to generalize this by induction (noting that it should actually it should be $m!$, not $(m-1)!$).

Comment: @Ian Okay, this makes sense. This a problem of section 3.6.3 of Sheldon Ross Probability's book, and he says that $c=(m-1)!$, so I don't know if is $c=m!$

Comment: For $m>2$ the calculation is rather formal to me, but for $m=2$ it is very clear: the region is a triangle under the diagonal of the unit square. So it definitely doesn't have area $1$.

Comment: @Did, in your first comment, you say "the integral is not over the $m$-dimensional cube $p_{i}\in [0,1]$ for every $i$ but over the $(m−1)$-dimensional intersection of this cube with the hyperplane $p_{1}+⋯+p_{m}=1$". So what  is the reason the integral is not over the $m$-dimensional cube??

Comment: The reason is written in your question itself: the function $f$ is nonzero only on the hyperplane of equation $p_1+\cdots+p_m=1$ and the $m$-dimensional Lebesgue measure of this hyperplane is zero hence the integral of $f$ on $\mathbb R^m$ is zero. Fortunately, all this is irrelevant to the exercise since $f$ is a PDF *considered as a function on the hyperplane* (and even, as a function defined on the unit simplex included in this hyperplane).